# Kernel panic: "Machine check: processor context corrupt" after install

Tags: nvidia, kernel

I am new to Linux and I am having issues after installing Ubuntu. I have tried multiple versions and all seem to give me the same issue. The Ubuntu Live CD worked and I used it to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7. I got the following error after installing Ubuntu.

```
Kernel panic: "Machine check: processor context corrupt"
```

System specs:

- x58 motherboard
- 12GB RAM
- Core i7 processor
- 2 Nvidia GTX 580 video cards in SLI configuration

Comment: Might want to check your photography skills again.. they are too blurry just write down what you get instead.

Comment: @UriHerrera Better-quality screenshots seem to have been posted. To the OP: after a quick Google search, it sounds like this might be a [problem with your hardware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_Check_Exception).

Comment: thanks for the reply WarriorIng64. my pc runs fine on win7 so i am guessing its not defective hardware. So is this a hardware incompatibility issue or something other? I'm a bit clueless at this point. I'm open to suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running the memory tester from the install CD or GRUB menu(if you have one listed there). If there are no problems, visit your BIOS config system and enter the CPU features submenu. Disable SpeedStep, TurboMode, CxE, Virtualization, HT technology, QPI controller setting, and link fast mode. Keep resetting each until the system fails to boot, and leave it as such.

Refer to http://www.evga.com/support/manuals/files/132-BL-E758.pdf for BIOS manual

Comment: so far seems like disabling speedstep has done the job. was able to bott into unbuntu anyway. time to play and see what happens . ty all for the suppost, much appreciated

Comment: Remember: You can try turning all other options back on to get better performance, but if another causes issues, turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

Solution
So basically we need to set up intel_idle module to use a simplified C-state logic. In order to do that, add `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` entry to the kernel command line in `/etc/default/grub`.

For instance:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="biosdevname=0 crashkernel=auto nomodeset rd.auto=1 consoleblank=0 intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
```

Then please regenerated GRUB configuration:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

or better

```
update-grub
```

then

```
reboot now
```

You will need to reboot your server to apply the new configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Was your system a assembled one or the ready-made CPU. The reason is the mother board chip-set is not matching the processor. Win7 will run fine as it is adaptable to the lower chip-set drivers to the next phase of processors and the mother board can also show no resistance to work in that case.

Ubuntu is Linux based as you know and is more secured because of the restriction that it should have the predefined set of chip-set drivers of the OEM recommendation for that security,which is mandatory for running. Try changing your mother board to the latest available chip-set that can suite to Intel i7. I had the same problem and tried many options. finally understood that from the AMD (mine is phenom II X2 555 black processor) that this processor requires a chip-set above AMD 760G while i was using 740G and win7 works for me very fine. now i changed new mother board to 760G chip set and every thing is fine and my performance also increased. YOur processor is recommended to have intel 1115 with Q77 or Z77 chip set and u r using X58 please look the review once again in the intel website and take decision